# What type of exception should the web API controller 'create' action throw in case the creation was not successful?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, asp.net-core-webapi

There are an ASP.NET Core Web API project and a controller in it. The controller has an action to create something. The creation itself is done by a different service, so that action just calls that service with proper arguments.

If the service returns `null`, I consider the creation failed and would like to signal that somehow. Here is the pseudo-code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Create(SomeEntityInfo someEntityInfo)
{
    // ...    
    var x = await _someService.CreateSomeEntityAsync(someEntityInfo).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
    {
        // What type of exception should be thrown here?
    }

    return CreatedAtAction(...);
}
```

So, what type of exception should be thrown in this case? Or is it better to return some special type of the `ObjectResult`?

Comment: Throw [InvalidOperationException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidoperationexception).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the failure is a result of an improper request made by the user, I'd not throw any exception in your code but I will return a HTTP 400 - Bad Request to the user, along with a message explaining why the request is not correct.

If the failure comes from within your service, due to an exception thrown for example, then I'd catch the exception in the controller method and return a HTTP 500 - Internal Server Error to the user.

So, It would look like :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Create(SomeEntityInfo someEntityInfo) {
        // ...    
        try
        {
            var x = await _someService.CreateSomeEntityAsync(someEntityInfo).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)) {
                return BadRequest($"{nameof(someEntityInfo)} parameter is not valid");
            }
            return CreatedAtAction(...);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //log exception somewhere
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
            return "Service failed, that's unfortunate.";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you think `BadRequest` is appropriate even in the case when parameters are valid, but `null` is returned for some other reason?

Comment: @YanSklyarenko is null expected by the client? If it is documented that the service can return a null under certain conditions and that is not a service failure, and if that is ok for the client, then I think you can return safely a string.Empty with an Ok(string.Empty) object (HTTP 200). I wouldn't be shocked by an API like this.